# reading csv file for specific information

Tags: c++, csv

I am wondering how to read a specific value from a csv file in C++, and then read the next four items in the file. For example, this is what the file would look like:

```
fire,2.11,2,445,7891.22,water,234,332.11,355,5654.44,air,4535,122,334.222,16,earth,453,46,77.3,454
```

What I want to do is let my user select one of the values, let's say "air" and also read the next four items(`4535 122 334.222 16`).

I only want to use `fstream,iostream,iomanip` libraries. I am a newbie, and I am horrible at writing code, so please, be gentle.

Comment: well, if you have bug with your code you can post it here and asked what the cause of the bug rather than this vague post.

Comment: There are already a lot of questions (with answers) on how to parse csv files  (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B]+reading+csv). I would start there....

Answer (score 0):

You should read about parsers. [Full CSV specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

If your fields are free of commas and double quotes, and you need a quick solution, search for `getline`/`strtok`, or try this (not compiled/tested):

```
typedef std::vector< std::string > svector;

bool get_line( std::istream& is, svector& d, const char sep = ',' )
{
  d.clear();
  if ( ! is )
    return false;

  char c;
  std::string s;
  while ( is.get(c) && c != '\n' )
  {
    if ( c == sep )
    {
      d.push_back( s );
      s.clear();
    }
    else
    {
      s += c;
    }
  }
  if ( ! s.empty() )
    d.push_back( s );

  return ! s.empty();
}

int main()
{
  std::ifstream is( "test.txt" );
  if ( ! is )
    return -1;
  svector line;
  while ( get_line( is, line ) )
  {
    //...
  }
  return 0;
}
```